How to Prevent Component Splitting Across Pages in A4 Layout Using React and react-to-print?
I am building a React application where I need to render content on A4-sized pages for printing. I’m using the react-to-print library to handle the printing functionality.
The issue I’m facing is that when a component (e.g., a block of text or an element) is too large to fit on the current page, it gets split across pages. Instead, I want the entire component to move to the next page if it doesn’t fit completely on the current one.
I’ve tried setting up the layout with @page CSS for A4 size and used overflow: hidden to manage content. However, react-to-print doesn't seem to support this behavior out of the box.
Is there any way to achieve this behavior with react-to-print or another library? Any advice on managing dynamic layouts for A4 pages in React would be greatly appreciated!
Here’s a snippet of the code I’ve tried:
import { useReactToPrint } from "react-to-print";
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const PrintableComponent = () => {
  const documentRef = useRef(null);

  const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => documentRef.current,
    documentTitle: "",
    onAfterPrint: () => console.log("Printed successfully!"),
    onBeforeGetContent: () => {
      console.log("Preparing content for print...");
    },
    onPrintError: (e) => console.error("Error during printing:", e),
  });

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handlePrint}>Print</button>
      <PrintableTemplate ref={documentRef} data={data} />
    </>
  );
};

The PrintableTemplate component includes a list of rows, where each row has text or elements. The issue is that rows split across pages during printing, and I’m trying to prevent that.

Hello. Have you read the react-to-print README section on page breaks? You should be able to use that to solve your issue
